# How to wait for a redux thunk that executes a promise when called from another thunk in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, redux-thunk

I have a main thunk that gets executed when clicking a button. Inside this thunk I want to call another thunk and wait for it to complete before moving forward. The second thunk executes a promise with nested promises. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to wait for the second thunk to complete its asynchronous operations.

I have tried using the `return` keyword on my thunk to make the call synchronous. I can't use the async keywords since I need this to work in IE 11.

I have also tried to make my second thunk return a promise and then do something like this `dispatch(secondThunk()).then(...)` but then it says that my thunk doesn't actually return a promise.

Here is some of my code:

```
export function mainThunk(): ThunkAction<void, void, void, AnyAction> {
    return (dispatch: Dispatch<any>) => {
    ...do some stuff
    dispatch(secondThunk());
    ...do other stuff
    };
}

export function secondThunk(): ThunkAction<void, void, void, AnyAction> {
    return (dispatch: Dispatch<any>) => {
      return new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any) => {
        someAsyncFunction()
        .then((response) => {
           return Promise.all(someArray.map(someId => {
             return someOtherAsyncFunction(someId):
         }));
        })
        .then((responses) => {
           response.foreach(response => {
             dispatch(someReduxAction(response.someField));
           });
        })
        .then(() => {
          resolve();
        });
    });
    };
}
```

When I run my code the mainThunk is not waiting for the secondThunk to complete before executing. Can you help me figure out how to make this work?

Answer (score -1):

You're almost there. In your mainThunk function you need to wait for the promise to resolve or reject. I've written my demo in Javascript and not Typescript. However the principles are the same. [Code-sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/4x9n6xp1z0)

```
import axios from "axios";

function mainThunk() {
  secondThunk()
    .then(data => {
      console.log("success");
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log("something went wrong");
      console.log(e);
    });
}

function secondThunk() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
      .get("https://swapi.co/api/people/")
      .then(people => {
        someOtherAsyncFunction().then(planets => {
          const response = {
            planets: planets,
            people: people
          };
          resolve(response);
        });
      })
      .catch(e => {
        reject(e);
      });
  });
}

function someOtherAsyncFunction() {
  return axios.get("https://swapi.co/api/planets/").then(response => {
    return response;
  });
}

mainThunk();
```

Comment: However this is using thunk action creators which is different from what you have there. As you see I have to call the secondThunk using dispatch and I'm also using TypeScript. When I try to do `then` on the secondThunk` I get the error `property then does not exist in on type ThunkAction`